# new Authorization Server Custom Login Page

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, authorization-server

I am using new Spring Authorization Server

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

I wan to configure custom login page. I have two beans configured

**AuthorizationServerConfig.java**

```
   @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);

        return http.cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .formLogin()
                .and().build();
    }
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
 @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors(withDefaults())
                .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                        authorizeRequests.mvcMatchers("/custom-login", "/css/**", "/js**", "/image/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/custom-login").failureForwardUrl("/custom-login?error");
        return http.build();
    }
```

Whenever User enter incorrect credentials is not being directed to `/custom-login?error`
He is directed to `/custom-login`

I seems `.failureForwardUrl("/custom-login?error");` is not working

If don't use custom login page user is being directed to `/login?error=some-error`

Can someone help to solve this problem?

Comment: Facing the same issue. Did you find any solution @Navigator?

Comment: solved. check the answer. @Ravidra

Comment: Thanks. It worked for the login failures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem.

I changed the configuration to

**AuthorizationServerCOnfig.java**

```
@Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);

        return http
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .formLogin().loginPage("/custom-login").failureForwardUrl("/custom-login?error=true")
                .and()
                .build();
    }
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
  @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors(withDefaults())
                .formLogin().failureForwardUrl("/custom-login")

        return http.build();
    }
```

I added **LoginController.java** to handle custom-login redirects.

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @GetMapping("/custom-login")
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }


    @PostMapping("/custom-login")
    public String loginFailed() {
        return "redirect:/authenticate?error=invalid username or password";
    }
}
```

*If you don't specify those end points. you will be redirected to /login*

Also I had both

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

And

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

My service was both authorization server and resource server at the same time.
So I removed

```
  <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

And every thing works expectedly